# Javafx: multiple keylisteners at once

Tags: java, javafx, keylistener

I'm trying to recreate the game Pong in Javafx, but i ran into a problem with the movement of the platforms.

I'm using the keylisteners and switch statements to move the platforms up and down. The left one with W and S and the right one with Up and Down.

It works fine when i press them seperatly, but not when I want to move them at the same time.

```
    package application;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        try {
            BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
            Scene scene = new Scene(root,700,400);
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();
            scene.setFill(Color.BLACK);

            Rectangle player1 = new Rectangle();
            player1.setWidth(10);
            player1.setHeight(50);
            player1.setY(175);
            player1.setX(10);
            player1.setFill(Color.WHITE);
            root.getChildren().add(player1);

            Rectangle player2 = new Rectangle();
            player2.setWidth(10);
            player2.setHeight(50);
            player2.setY(175);
            player2.setX(680);
            player2.setFill(Color.WHITE);
            root.getChildren().add(player2);


            scene.setOnKeyPressed(new EventHandler<KeyEvent>(){ 
                public void handle(KeyEvent event) {
                    switch(event.getCode()) {
                    case W: if(player1.getY() -3 >= 0) {player1.setY(player1.getY()- 4);} break;
                    case S: if(player1.getY() +53 <= 400) {player1.setY(player1.getY()+4);} break;
                    case UP: if(player2.getY() -3 >= 0) {player2.setY(player2.getY()- 4);} break;
                    case DOWN: if(player2.getY() +53 <= 400) {player2.setY(player2.getY()+4);} break;
                    }
                }
            });


        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: I didn't try it, but you should try to write `scene#setOnKeyPlayer1Pressed` where you have to handle `W` and `S` keys, **AND** `scene#setOnKeyPlayer2Pressed`, handling `UP` and `DOWN`...

Answer (score 2):

JavaFX processes only one KeyCode in an event handler. So there is no way to check for multiple key codes from a keyevent object. However it do processes all KeyCodes that are pressed in a sequential manner. So if you press A & B at a time, it processes events for A & B in the order they are pressed. So taking advantage of this feature we can tweak a bit and handle multi key press event handling.

Considering for your example, keep registering all the key codes(in a set) that come through pressed event handler and perform your logic accordingly. And ensure to clear the set on key released. This way we can know which keys are pressed together.

Below is the code that demonstrates my above explanation. And it worked in your example :)

```
final List<KeyCode> acceptedCodes = Arrays.asList(KeyCode.S, KeyCode.W, KeyCode.UP, KeyCode.DOWN);
            final Set<KeyCode> codes = new HashSet<>();
            scene.setOnKeyReleased(e -> codes.clear());
            scene.setOnKeyPressed(e -> {
                if (acceptedCodes.contains(e.getCode())) {
                    codes.add(e.getCode());
                    if (codes.contains(KeyCode.W)) {
                        if (player1.getY() - 3 >= 0) {
                            player1.setY(player1.getY() - 4);
                        }
                    } else if (codes.contains(KeyCode.S)) {
                        if (player1.getY() + 53 <= 400) {
                            player1.setY(player1.getY() + 4);
                        }
                    }
                    if (codes.contains(KeyCode.UP)) {
                        if (player2.getY() - 3 >= 0) {
                            player2.setY(player2.getY() - 4);
                        }
                    } else if (codes.contains(KeyCode.DOWN)) {
                        if (player2.getY() + 53 <= 400) {
                            player2.setY(player2.getY() + 4);
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
```