# How can I track the pressing of two or more keys?

Tags: java, javafx

I need to track a combination of two buttons. I wrote this code, but it does not work correctly.

```
primaryStage.addEventFilter(KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED, new EventHandler<KeyEvent>(){
            public void handle(KeyEvent event){
                if(event.getCode() == UP && event.getCode() == RIGHT){camera.cameraControlXY(-0.5,0.5);};
            }
        });
```

In the sample code there is only one function, in the full code there are other functions, separately for each key. When you press a combination, functions for individual keys are triggered. I found similar questions, but the answers did not clarify the situation. I saw a lot of similar listeners for pressing buttons and I don’t really understand how they differ. thanks in advance for your reply

Comment: Use a `Set`.  On each key press, you put the key in the `Set`, on each release, you remove it.  You then have a "processing" method which make determinations about what to do based on what's in the `Set`

Comment: As @MadProgrammer said, using Set can help you. A bit more info can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52580865/javafx-multiple-keylisteners-at-once/52582921#52582921)

Comment: OK I understood. I will deal with it. And you could not even poke where to look, to understand how to track the duration of pressing a key?@MadProgrammer